# Automatic way of generating accessor classes in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, class, private

I've got the following problem. Suppose, that there is a class, which contains a private class, which have to be tested. To cut off unnecessary comments and answers, **yes** it has to stay private and **yes**, it have to be tested.

Say, it looks like this:

```
public class PublicClass
{
    private class InternalClass
    {
        void Method() { }
    }
}
```

For ease and convenience of testing, I would like to create the following class:

```
public class InternalClassAccess
{
    private object instance;

    public InternalClassAccess()
    {
        // Use reflections to instantiate InternalClass
        // and store it in instance field
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        // Use reflections to call Method() on
        // stored instance
    }
}
```

I can write such class manually, but I wonder, if there is some kind of automatic way of doing so? I have Professional version of VS 2012.

Comment: "yes it has to stay private" -- If it has to stay private, but it also has to be accessible outside of `PublicClass`, something is wrong with your design. You don't explain why it has to be `private`, and I cannot imagine why it would be a problem to make it `internal`.

Comment: plus if it is `internal`, you could add `[InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` and specify your test project; then your test project has access.

Comment: It should *not* be accessible outside the `PublicClass` *in terms of the project*. On the other hand, I wish to test it, so i have to gain access to this class (or other private members). Imagine a huge class with one method DoSomethingComplicatedAndExtremelySpecific and 100s of small, private methods, which do something even more extremely specific (so they should not be visible and shouldn't be extracted), but what influences the final result (so they should be tested). I explicitly wrote the *not*'s to cut off comments about privacy of methods and need of test. Please accept these facts.

Comment: @Spook: That sounds like something which could do with being refactored anyway. Heck, it sounds like it could be a whole separate assembly, with a single public class and loads of internal ones - which you could then test using `InternalsVisibleTo`.

Comment: Imagine the class JPeg, which allows you to compress and save raw byte[] into file as Jpeg. This class belongs to bigger assembly with similar classes: Png, Tiff etc. Class exports two public methods: Save and Load, but contains a few private methods, which actually does the work. They shouldn't be internal, because noone despite this class uses them. Would you test these or not?

Comment: @Spook "They shouldn't be internal, because noone despite this class uses them." -- That's just it: if the test class uses them, someone other than the `JPeg` class *does* use them. (I don't expect this to change your mind, but the comments here are also for the benefit of others asking a similar question.)

Comment: That effects in changing program's architecture especially for tests and I surely don't like it. I think, that it shall be done the other way and that's why I'm asking the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything built into .NET for this - but you can write your class *once* for all such classes using `dynamic`. You'd have a structure something like this:

```
public class PrivateDynamicAccessor : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly object instance;

    public PrivateDynamicAccessor(string typeName)
    {
        // Instantiate here via reflection
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
                                      out Object result)
    {
        // Access the fields or properties with reflection
    }
}
```

(Likewise `TryInvokeMember` for methods, etc.)

Then you can use it as:

```
dynamic foo = new PrivateDynamicAccessor("Foo.Bar+Baz");
string name = foo.Name;
// etc
```

(I agree with the comment that it's odd to have to do this, mind you. You *really* can't make it internal?)

Comment: `You really can't make it internal?` - Making this class internal instead of private is like modifying serial body of a car, such that a crash-cam can be mounted inside. Don't you think, that modifying architecture of program to fit unit testing is wrong?

Comment: @Spook: Not really - the fact that you can't unit test it is a code smell. The fact that you've got "a huge class with one method DoSomethingComplicatedAndExtremelySpecific and 100s of small, private methods" is a code smell, IMO. It doesn't sound sufficiently focused to me.

Comment: I would answer here, "one size does not fit all". Currently I'm performing quite complicated image analysis and my class is a black box - it receives image and returns some data extracted from it. However the process is very specific and quite complicated, so there are really many private *specific* methods, that shouldn't be exposed, but should be tested. Suppose for a moment, that these methods are private as an architecture requirement of the project - would you test them? Or expose to bigger audience by making them internal?

Comment: Imagine a car engine - it's a huge piece of technology, but its "public interface" is just: turn the key, it starts to rotate; press the accelerator pedal, it rotates faster. All its parts are hidden inside (private). The class I'm talking about is quite similar, but I think, that there are much more cases, when such decision to hide many methods by making them private is judged.

Comment: Car parts might be 'hidden' in the car but many parts are replaceable, autonomous objects with public interfaces.

Comment: What can I say, that's true too. I suppose, that's a subject for a longer discussion, answer's comments are not supposed to serve this purpose :)

Comment: @Spook: Yeah, I don't think we're going to make any progress to be honest - but it still sounds like a code smell to me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some preprocessing directives:

```
public class PublicClass
{
    #if DEBUG
    public class InternalClass
    #else
    private class InternalClass
    #endif
    {
        void Method() { }
    }
}

//Only valid when testing in Debug
public class TestableInternalClass : PublicClass.InternalClass
{

}
```

Comment: As much as I hate to use macros and compiler directives, this is actually quite a good idea, because it keeps the encapsulation *on the project level* (eg. you may have special directive only for tests). I'd consider that a last resort tool, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate you can just right-click the method/constructor and pick generate test. This will create an Accessor class for the outer class that allows you to access the private inner class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no such option in the context menu. Which version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: I tested this in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have Professional version of VS; I guess, that this functionality is available in Test Suite and Ultimate versions only...